# pivot table creation on different sheets fails on second sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am new in VBA programming and this is one my first codes i am writing.

**Purpose of code**: I'd like to take data on Invoices sheet and take it apart to different sheets based on the last column. Then on each sheet create a pivot table for the data.

The code is quite long - i am sure there are quite a lot of unnecessary steps in it but it is 90% ok.
The frist sheet is created perfectly. The first pivot is also created. Then the second sheet is also created.

**Problem**: The macro runs on an error when it tries to create the pivot table for the second sheet.

**Error message**: Run-time error'5': Invalid Procedure call or argument

Does anyone have an idea why my macro fails on the second sheet? Thank You for your help!
Pleaase see the code below. The problem occurs after the comment of creating a pivot table

```
Sub copypaste()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Declarations
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim Counter As Integer


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Invoices")
Counter = 0
Debug.Print Counter

'get the number of rows in the invoices sheet
LastRow = ws2.Range("A1", ws2.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

'plus invoice type and sum column creation
ws2.Select
Columns(6).Select
Range("F:F").Insert
Cells(1, 6) = "Invoice type"
Range("F2:F" & LastRow).Formula = "=LEFT(RC[1],4)"
Selection.Columns.AutoFit
Columns(19).Select
Range("S:S").Insert
Cells(1, 19) = "Sum"
Range("S2:S" & LastRow).Formula = "=SUM(RC[-8]:RC[-1])"
Selection.Style = "Comma"
Selection.NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.0 _F_t_-;-* #,##0.0 _F_t_-;_-* ""-""?? _F_t_-;_-@_-"
Selection.NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0 _F_t_-;-* #,##0 _F_t_-;_-* ""-""?? _F_t_-;_-@_-"
Selection.Columns.AutoFit

'sorbarendezés debtor name és invoice no. szerint
ws2.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Range("A1:R" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("E1"), Header:=xlYes, Key2:=Range("G1")

'list creation as a basis for filtering and taking apart the data

wb.Activate
ws2.Select
Range("A1").Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Set ws3 = Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:= _
    xlYes
Range("A2").Select
Set rng1 = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))
ws3.Select
ws3.Name = "kódolás"
Set ws = wb.Sheets("kódolás")

wb.Activate
ws.Select
'go through the earlier created list and take apart the data related to each item of the list to separate sheets
For Each cell In rng1
    Counter = Counter + 1
    Debug.Print Counter
    'filtered data copy
    ws2.Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ws2.Range("$A$1:$W$198162").AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=cell
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Copy
    'new sheet creation
    With wb
        .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
            Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    'filtered data paste
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'go back to A1
    Range("A1").Select



    'Creation of pivot table


    
    LastRow2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
    
    ActiveCell.Range("A1:T" & LastRow2).Select
    
    Debug.Print Counter
    Debug.Print LastRow2
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & "R1C1:R" & LastRow2 & "C19"
    Debug.Print ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & "R1C23"
    Debug.Print "PivotTable" & Counter
    
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & "R1C1:R" & LastRow2 & "C19", Version:=6).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & "R1C23", TableName:="PivotTable" & Counter, DefaultVersion:=6
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Cells(1, 27).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable" & Counter)
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable" & Counter).PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable" & Counter).RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable" & Counter).PivotFields("Debtor name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable" & Counter).PivotFields("invoice type")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable" & Counter).AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable" & Counter).PivotFields("SUM"), "Sum of SUM", xlSum 
    
    'take out filter and go back to A1
    ws2.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1").Select
    ws2.AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). I highly recommend to get rid of all `.Select` and `.Activate` statements with this technique. This will very likely fix your issues.

Comment: Does the sheet name have spaces in it? To be safe, there should be a single quote before and after the sheet name in the string you pass to `SourceData:=`.

Comment: Yes the second aheet name has space in it. Ok i'll try.

Comment: I'll try to elinimate the select andd activate codes. Thanks

Comment: The space was the problem of the code. now it runs ok (not smoothly due to the lot of selection and activation but ok)